# Wordpress: Allow Contributor to edit other post and publish with moderation

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I need to allow contributors to edit other post and publish posts but keeping the moderation.
Because, i modify the capabilities  publish_posts and edit_others_posts, there is no more moderation.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a system where the contributor only able to add new and save for review, not publishing the post. When admin approve the post, the post made published. But as far as I can understand that's not what happening in your system, right?

In that case I would like to suggest you to keep a backup, reinstall the core files (except config file)

Also, delete and re-add a .htaccess file.

Then reset your permalinks.

Hope that's gonna helps any.

Also, disable all plugins and see if there is some plugin affecting the contributor role.

I can’t think of any reason why a Contributor should be able to publish.

More you can find here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: Yes thats's happen like this by default but not if allow  publish_posts and edit_others_posts

Comment: So what do you want now?

Comment: how to maintain moderation even while authorizing contributors to edit other post and publish

Comment: If we provide contributor capabilities to edit post and publish, again you want to moderate? Then what is the problem with default capabilities. That's thing you wanted, right?

Comment: with default contributors capabilities, their post are moderate but they can't edit (no button) other's post. If i add edit_others_post they now can do it but there is no moderation and i need one.

Comment: actually, i would like that all post poublished or modified by contributors has a status "Pending Review"

Comment: Which is already a default property of contributor. Just stop providing capabilities to edit post and publish.

Comment: not exactly...when i add this capabilities, it's like my contributor become author and so there is no more moderation